# Typescript error while calling axios - no overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I'm calling axios and passing in a config object like the following:

```
const req = { method, url, timeout: 300000, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }

axios(req)
```

I'm getting a typescript error that says "No overload matches this call". The axios function takes on a config object of the type `AxiosRequestConfig`:

`axios(config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosPromise<any>`

For your reference, here is what the `AxiosRequestConfig` type looks like, along with the `Method` type:

```
interface AxiosRequestConfig {
  url?: string;
  method?: Method;
  baseURL?: string;
  transformRequest?: AxiosTransformer | AxiosTransformer[];
  transformResponse?: AxiosTransformer | AxiosTransformer[];
  headers?: any;
  params?: any;
  paramsSerializer?: (params: any) => string;
  data?: any;
  timeout?: number;
  timeoutErrorMessage?: string;
  withCredentials?: boolean;
  adapter?: AxiosAdapter;
  auth?: AxiosBasicCredentials;
  responseType?: ResponseType;
  xsrfCookieName?: string;
  xsrfHeaderName?: string;
  onUploadProgress?: (progressEvent: any) => void;
  onDownloadProgress?: (progressEvent: any) => void;
  maxContentLength?: number;
  validateStatus?: (status: number) => boolean;
  maxRedirects?: number;
  socketPath?: string | null;
  httpAgent?: any;
  httpsAgent?: any;
  proxy?: AxiosProxyConfig | false;
  cancelToken?: CancelToken;
}

type Method =
  | 'get' | 'GET'
  | 'delete' | 'DELETE'
  | 'head' | 'HEAD'
  | 'options' | 'OPTIONS'
  | 'post' | 'POST'
  | 'put' | 'PUT'
  | 'patch' | 'PATCH'
  | 'link' | 'LINK'
  | 'unlink' | 'UNLINK'
```

I don't understand this error, because it seems like my config object satisfies this interface just fine. And here's where it gets extra confusing to me: if I change the type definition of `AxiosRequestConfig` so that

```
method?: String;
```

instead of

```
method?: Method
```

Then the typescript error disappears. Also, if I try to spread in my config object and manually add a method property like the following:

```
axios({...req, method: 'GET'})
```

The error disappears again. But I have to add the method property in... if I just spread in my config object I get the same error as before.

So it seems like the error may be linked to the method property of the AxiosRequestConfig interface, but ultimately I'm not sure. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does it say if you specify the type of `req`, i.e. `const req: AxiosRequestConfig = { ... }`?

Comment: What if you cast the req object as Axios config ?

Comment: Well the error on the axios call does go away, but it's telling me: Cannot find name 'AxiosRequestConfig'

Comment: I tried importing the interface, and now the error says: is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestConfig'

Comment: It also says: Types of property 'method' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"POST" | "PUT" | "GET" | "DELETE" | "get" | "delete" | "head" | "HEAD" | "options" | "OPTIONS" | "post" | "put" | "patch" | "PATCH" | "link" | "LINK" | "unlink" | "UNLINK" | undefined'.

Comment: For the `method` incompatibility, you can cast the value to type `Method`, for example:  `axios({...req, method: 'GET' as Method })`.

Comment: It seems like your local axios typescript definition file is different than this one

Answer (score 12):

**This is a very straightforward Answer.**

**add**

> AxiosRequestConfig

**in your import statement like this**

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse} from 'axios';
```

and then go down below where your config code is and just assign **AxiosRequestConfig** interface to your **config variable** like this

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      method: 'get',
      url: `${quickbooksBaseURL}/v3/company/${QuickbooksCustomerID}/invoice/${invoiceID}/pdf?minorversion=${minorVersion}`,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    };
    const response: AxiosResponse = await axios(config);
```

**doing this work for me and I hope it will work for you, too.**

Comment: Yes, the problem is that "method" can to be of type "Method" or "any" but can NOT be of string type. So you could write something like this: `axios({..., method: method as any, ..});`